# Identify the previous row values satisfying the condition in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I need to identify the previous rows values which meet a condition. For the given row, the value from the previous row where the timestamp< 'timestamp_pre get the maximum cum_id and its value.

for eg:
input:

```
ID          timestamp  com_id   Value   timestamp_Pre
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:27      2    33  2023-1-5 06:33:20
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:33      3    22  2023-1-5 06:33:28
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:39      4    44  2023-1-5 06:33:28
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:45      NA   11  2023-1-5 06:33:35
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:51      NA   99  NA
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:57      NA   88  2023-1-5 06:33:44
```

output:

```
ID          timestamp  com_id   Value   timestamp_Pre   com_id_pre  value_pre
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:27      2    33  2023-1-5 06:33:20      NA   NA
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:33      3    22  2023-1-5 06:33:28       2   33
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:39      4    44  2023-1-5 06:33:28       2   33
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:45      NA   11  2023-1-5 06:33:35       3   22      
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:51      NA   99  NA                      NA  NA
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:57      NA   88  2023-1-5 06:33:44       4   44
```

Consider row number 4, its com_id_pre and value_pre should be from the previous row whose timestamp is < 2023-1-5 06:33:35

code used:

```
m=(df['timestamp']<df['timestamp_Pre']) & (df['com_id']>0)
df['com_id_pre']=df[m].groupby('id)['com_id'].transform('max')

df['com_id_pre']=df['com_id'].where(df['timestamp']<df['timestamp_Pre']).transform('max')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with remove rows with missing values by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with left join:

```
df = df.merge(pd.merge_asof(df.dropna(subset=['timestamp_Pre']), df, 
                   left_on='timestamp_Pre', 
                   right_on='timestamp',
                   allow_exact_matches=False,
                   by='ID',
                   suffixes=('','_pre')).drop(['timestamp_Pre_pre','timestamp_pre'],axis=1),
              how='left')
print (df)
   ID           timestamp  com_id  Value       timestamp_Pre  com_id_pre  \
0  aa 2023-01-05 06:33:27     2.0     33 2023-01-05 06:33:20         NaN   
1  aa 2023-01-05 06:33:33     3.0     22 2023-01-05 06:33:28         2.0   
2  aa 2023-01-05 06:33:39     4.0     44 2023-01-05 06:33:28         2.0   
3  aa 2023-01-05 06:33:45     NaN     11 2023-01-05 06:33:35         3.0   
4  aa 2023-01-05 06:33:51     NaN     99                 NaT         NaN   
5  aa 2023-01-05 06:33:57     NaN     88 2023-01-05 06:33:44         4.0   

   Value_pre  
0        NaN  
1       33.0  
2       33.0  
3       22.0  
4        NaN  
5       44.0
```

Or repalce missing values by smallest possible `Timestamp`, processing and last replace to missing values:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df['timestamp_Pre'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp_Pre'])

df =( pd.merge_asof(df.fillna({'timestamp_Pre':pd.Timestamp.min})
                      .sort_values('timestamp_Pre').reset_index(), 
                   df, 
                   left_on='timestamp_Pre', 
                   right_on='timestamp',
                   allow_exact_matches=False,
                   by='ID',
                   suffixes=('','_pre'))
         .sort_values('index', ignore_index=True)
         .drop(['timestamp_Pre_pre','timestamp_pre','index'], axis=1)
         .assign(timestamp_Pre = lambda x: x['timestamp_Pre']
                                 .mask(x['timestamp_Pre'].dt.year.eq(1677))))
print (df)
   ID           timestamp  com_id  Value       timestamp_Pre  com_id_pre  \
0  aa 2023-01-05 06:33:27     2.0     33 2023-01-05 06:33:20         NaN   
1  aa 2023-01-05 06:33:33     3.0     22 2023-01-05 06:33:28         2.0   
2  aa 2023-01-05 06:33:39     4.0     44 2023-01-05 06:33:28         2.0   
3  aa 2023-01-05 06:33:45     NaN     11 2023-01-05 06:33:35         3.0   
4  aa 2023-01-05 06:33:51     NaN     99                 NaT         NaN   
5  aa 2023-01-05 06:33:57     NaN     88 2023-01-05 06:33:44         4.0   

   Value_pre  
0        NaN  
1       33.0  
2       33.0  
3       22.0  
4        NaN  
5       44.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) for this:

```py
# sort the values in the desired order of priority (top = higher)
# this could be on several columns, here we put higher com_id on top
df2 = df.sort_values(by='com_id', ascending=False)

# ensure datetime type
df2[['timestamp', 'timestamp_Pre']] = df2[['timestamp', 'timestamp_Pre']
                                          ].apply(pd.to_datetime)

# identify timestamp_Pre that are greater than timestamp
m = (df2['timestamp_Pre'].to_numpy()[:,None] > df2['timestamp'].to_numpy())

# get first valid index per timestamp_Pre
m2 = m.any(axis=1)
idx = df2.index[m.argmax(axis=1)][m2]

# assign as new columns
out = df.join(df2.loc[idx, ['com_id', 'Value']]
                 .set_axis(df2.index[m2]).add_suffix('_pre')
              )
```

Output:

```
   ID          timestamp  com_id  Value      timestamp_Pre  com_id_pre  Value_pre
0  aa  2023-1-5 06:33:27     2.0     33  2023-1-5 06:33:20         NaN        NaN
1  aa  2023-1-5 06:33:33     3.0     22  2023-1-5 06:33:28         2.0       33.0
2  aa  2023-1-5 06:33:39     4.0     44  2023-1-5 06:33:28         2.0       33.0
3  aa  2023-1-5 06:33:45     NaN     11  2023-1-5 06:33:35         3.0       22.0
4  aa  2023-1-5 06:33:51     NaN     99                NaN         NaN        NaN
5  aa  2023-1-5 06:33:57     NaN     88  2023-1-5 06:33:44         4.0       44.0
```